# How to escape square brackets in hp ppm workbench

Tags: oracle

How to escape square brackets in hp ppm workbench inorder to use Regexp_substr command. Because Regexp_substr is having [^,] in the syntax and this is being considered as token in Hp ppm workbench.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('science,social',chr(91)||'^,'||chr(93)||'+',1,LEVEL) DATA
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH ('science,social') - LENGTH (REPLACE ('science,social', ',')) + 1
```

The character set is used to escape the open and close brackets

- Open Brackets:  `chr(91)`
- Close Brackets: `chr(93)`